# Don't understand why server won't respond to client (even after turning of firewall | Python | Server

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets, server, client-server

I set up my server on MacBook air and my client is connecting from a Windows 10 machine. I turned off all security and firewalls on both machines (because that's what you do when you've lost all hope) and tried to connect from my windows machine multiple times, but to no avail. I'm on the same network btw (not using a VM).

Error:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Server:

```
import socket, threading
import multiprocessing 
from time import sleep


# tells us the bytes of the message
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5430
# or you could do socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!END'

# defines the type of connection
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def start(): 
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()

        print('[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] 1')

start()
```

Client:

```
from time import sleep
import socket, subprocess

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5430
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!END' 
SERVER = '192.32.322.3' 
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
```

Comment: Can you ping between the machines? Where does the server get to in the code according to the print-outs?

Comment: And what address is `SERVER`? Is that on the same network as the other computer? Manually specifying the IP address or leaving it blank would be better.

Comment: Double checked the ip address and its correct. Tried to ping and got this: ping 192.168.100.153
PING 192.168.100.153 (192.168.100.153): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
^C
--- 192.168.100.153 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss (my server ip changed btw)

Comment: Carcigenicate the problem seemed to be that both my devices were connected to the wifi extension, when I switched to my main network it worked just fine. But I’m wondering why this would be an issue? Don’t they both act like a network?